# Duplicating a list N number of times

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to duplicate a list n number of times while preserving the order of the list itself. For example all I have right now and it doesn't work nor does it give me an error.

```
def duplicate(testList, n):
    y = 0
    x = len(testList)
    newList=[]
    while y < x:
        for z in range (0, n):
            newList.append(testList[y])
        y = y + 1
    return newList

duplicate([1,2,3], 3)
```

After this im not sure where to fix it.

The desired output is:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
>>> def duplicate(testList, n):
...     return [ele for ele in testList for _ in range(n)]
... 
>>> duplicate([1,2,3],2)
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
>>> duplicate([1,2,3],3)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

This would return a list where each element is repeated n times in the list, however beware of this

```
>>> duplicate([[1,2,3]],3)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

Or, if you want to replicate the list itself:

```
>>> def duplicate(testList, n):
...     return testList*n
... 
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> duplicate(x,3)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

The `testList*n` will create a new list consisting of `testList` `n` number of times, this is equivalent of (testList + testList + ....) `n` times

Answer (score 3):

To get the same output as your own code, `range` and `extend` will still work:

```
def duplicate(testList, n):
    x = len(testList)
    new_list = []
    for j in range(x):
        new_list.extend(testList[j] for _ in range(n))
    return new_list


print(duplicate([1, 2, 3], 3))
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Which could simply become a [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php):

```
def duplicate(testList, n):
    return [ele for ele in testList for _ in range(n)]
```

If you are not seeing output for any of the code then you are most likely running from an IDE and not printing the function return i.e `print(duplicate([1, 2, 3], 3))`.

Lastly if you were to index and use two loops and use `append` like your own code, you would use 2 range loops, there is no need for a while loop at all:

```
def duplicate(testList, n):
    x = len(testList)
    new_list = []
    for j in range(x):
        for _ in range(n):
            new_list.append(testList[j])
    return new_list
```

---

If you want `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` and you have to use loops, use a `range` loop and `extend`:

```
def duplicate(testList, n):
    new_list = [] 
    for i in range(n):
        new_list.extend(testList)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming sortable elements within the list, what about:

```
a = [1,2,3]
num_repeats = 3

a_expanded = a * num_repeats
a_expanded.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should actually switch the for loop and the while loop and remember to initialize y each time you loop.  Compare the variable y in your code and mine, and you will see that you actually want it to go 0,1,2,0,1,2.. so that it will go round and round and append the correct index.

```
def duplicate(testList, n):
    x = len(testList)
    newList=[]
    for z in range (0, n):
        y = 0
        while y < x:
            newList.append(testList[y])
            y = y + 1
    return newList

print duplicate([1,2,3], 3)
```

Comment: This gives `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]` but OP expected `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`.